# How to run a INSERT query in IF statement success/failer case

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
 **news:** id, subject, author, publisher 
 **locale:** news_id, lang_id, name
The table news is **one-to-many** relationship with locale.

In my website, 
  if new language is activated then i need to add activated language variable(take value from the corresponding new's default lang value) to the table locale
  if new language is deactivated then i need to remove activated language variable from the table locale
This process same for all the entries in the news table.

**For example:**-
 Table - news:
 
 id subject author  publisher
 1  sample1 author1 publisher1
 2  sample2 author2 publisher2

 Table - locale:
 news_id lang_id name
 1       1       news1 - german
 1       2       news1 - english
 1       3       news1 - french
 2       1       news2 - german
 2       2       news2 - english
 2       3       news2 - french

If i activate 'italian' lang, i need to add the following entry:
   news_id => 1 lang_id => 4 name => news1 - italian
   news_id => 2 lang_id => 4 name => news2 - italian

If i deactivate 'english' lang, i need to remove the following entry:
   news_id => 1 lang_id => 2 name => news1 - english
   news_id => 2 lang_id => 2 name => news2 - english

I need to complete this process by using MYSQL(single query).

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Your `locale` table appears to be an association table, but there's no underlying language table? Whilst you *could* populate new entries into such a `locale` table using `INSERT ... SELECT`,  one would typically include translated data (that is specific to each news/locale combination) which MySQL cannot provide automatically: thus such tasks are usually performed as part of an external, often manual, process. Furthermore, "deactivation" would rarely involve deleting underlying records (just mark them in some way), though cascading deletions to foreign key constraints could accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Query for language activation:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
                            `locale` 
                            (   `news_id`, 
                                `lang_id`, 
                                `name`
                            )
                        SELECT * FROM 
                            (SELECT `news_id`, 
                                    ' . $activatedLangId . ',
                                    `name` 
                                FROM `locale` 
                                WHERE lang_id = ' . $defaultLangId . '
                            ) as tmp
```

Query for language deactivation:

```
DELETE FROM `locale` WHERE lang_id = ' . $deactivatedLangId
```

Note: In the locale table, news_id and lang_id are indexed.